# Sum of a series using derivatives

Tags: probability, summation

$$1 + 2/2 + 3/4 + \cdots + n/2^{n-1}$$

How would find the closed-form expression and also the sum up to 20?
I'm not really getting why or the logic behind using derivatives to arrive at an answer.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) should give you plenty of ideas.

Comment: That question is not identical; answers are not asked to give the formula for a finite sum. I do see that within Eric Naslund's answer is a formula similar to mine for a finite sum; however, that answer does not use derivatives, which is one of the points of this question. In any case, I don't think this is really a duplicate, but I won't act unilaterally on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard geometric series is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\tag{1}
$$
Taking the derivative yields
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}kx^{k-1}
&=\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}(1-x)-(1-x^{n+1})(-1)}{(1-x)^2}\\
&=\frac{1-(n+1)x^{n}+nx^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Use $x=\frac12$ in $(2)$.

Comment: Don't you mean use $x=1/2$?

Comment: @RickDecker: which is what I wrote: Use $\color{#C00000}{x=\frac12}$ in $(2)$.

Comment: Oops. I read that as $x=\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$. Guess I should get my eyes checked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a arithmetico-geometric sequence and the computation of its sum is very standard : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico-geometric_sequence